# Conditional setTimeout call

Tags: javascript, node.js

As far as a I know, there is no way to get setTimeout to run synchronously.

I have this code, where foo is a decently long function (20 lines or so).

```
if(delay == null){
  function foo(){

  }()
}
else {
   setTimeout(function(){
     function foo(){

     }()
   }, delay);
 }
```

what would very convenient, would be if setTimeout would accept an delay argument of -1, and then would just run synchronously/immediately, something like this:

```
var delay = delay || -1;

   setTimeout(function(){
     function foo(){

     }()
   }, delay);  // if delay is -1, will run immediately.
```

I don't think this functionality works with setTimeout, is there another way I can prevent having to write out the foo function twice? The only good solution I have is to create a helper function, but that's not as convenient :)

Comment: You could change foo to run accordingly ? Passing a variable in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another way I can prevent having to write out the `foo` function twice?

Yep.

Define `foo`:

```
function foo() {

}
```

And then run it immediately if `delay === -1`, otherwise in a `setTimeout`:

```
if (delay === -1)
    foo();
else
    setTimeout(foo, delay);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function foo(){

}
if(delay == null){
  foo();
}
else {
   setTimeout(foo, delay);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really old, but you can simply just use an inline condition for the time delay.

```
setTimeout(foo, isDelay ? delay : 0)
```

Comment: `setTimeout(foo, 0);` might have an undesired effect.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Answer (score 0):

Mention "delay" time at least 1000 milisec.

```
setTimeout(foo, isDelay ? delay : 1000)
```